# Bootstrap4 Navbar doesn't work with "jQuery.BgSwitcher" in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

So I am using Bootstrap4 (Bootswatch4 to be more specific) and I need a div with changing/fading backgrounds. I found that js to be closest to what I want: https://github.com/rewish/jquery-bgswitcher
So I use it like this in https://jsfiddle.net/p5d8rskg/:

```
$(".banana").bgswitcher({
  images: ["image1.jpg", "image2.jpg"],
  interval: 5000,
  duration: 2000
});
```

Everything works fine in the desktop version. But the problem is that in mobile version the navbar goes over the div and pushes the content of the div outside. How can I fix this "bug"? Or are there simpler approaches to get the same effect as with "bgswitcher" without that "bug"?

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

More a hacky solution, but a workable one is to use `position: absolute` for your `.banana` container. This way the container is fixed to your defined position.

I have [updated your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p5d8rskg/10/) in order to show the solution:

```
nav {
    z-index: 1000 !important;
}

.banana {
    background-color: powderblue;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    background-size: cover;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 56px;
    left: 0;
}
```

Basically i added `position: absolute` as well as `top: 56px` (the height of your navbar) and `left: 0` to define the position. In order to bring your navbar to the front and not the text apply a bigger `z-index` to this element.

Good luck!